# Pi-calculator program gives different output each time it's run

Tags: c++, c, random, segmentation-fault, pi

This is a program to calculate the value of Pi using the fact that "The probability of any two integers being co-prime is 6/π<sup>2</sup>." This program compiled successfully but when I try to run it, it gives the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to change the condition statement in for-loop to *i < 9999*. By doing this, the program gives an output which varies(when run each time) between 3.000000, 3.162278 and Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I want to calculate the value of π only by using the property mentioned above. Please help.

Also, help me choose a better function that generates random numbers and suggest me some code improvements. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    // Everything divides 0 
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
       return 0;

    // base case
    if (a == b)
        return a;

    // a is greater
    if (a > b)
        return gcd(a-b, b);
    return gcd(a, b-a);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int numberOne = rand();
    int numberTwo = rand();
    int coprime = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
    {
        numberOne = rand();
        numberTwo = rand();

        if(gcd(numberOne, numberTwo) == 1)
        {
            coprime++;
        }

    }

    // co-prime/99999 = 6 / pi^2
    double pi = 599994/coprime;
    pi = sqrt(pi);

    printf("%f\n", pi);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My guess? Your recursion doesn't stop when you think it does. Have you tried using a debugger to catch the crash and see when and where it happens? Perhaps you should take some time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: your gdc function is causing a stack overflow. which implies you are missing an exit condition

Comment: I get "3.000000" every time when running your code

Comment: replace double pi = 599994/coprime; by double pi = 599994.0/static_cast<double>(coprime); You may be losing some digits from integer division.

Comment: @falopsy The cast should not be needed, as long as one of the operands is a `double`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, no you will need the cast. it will do the integer division before casting. What do you think double p=94/10; will give you? 9.4 or 9.0? Anyway, it is always good to cast to show intent.

Comment: @falopsy What do *you* think `double p = 94.0 / 10;` will give?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I agree but I think the stack overflow is because the recursion of the gcd function is too deep. What you need to do is limit the value of the random number generated (currently the limit you are using is RAND_MAX = 32767 on my computer). Maybe look at <random>, contains classes that let you generate random numbers within a limit. You can limit to like 1000.

Comment: @Bob__, how is that relevant? In the op's code, both arguments on the RHS are integer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm gonna try to do it without recursion.

Comment: You may consider the use of a couple of constants, like `const /* long long */ int N = 99999;` and `const double K = 6.0 * N;` to use in `double pi = K / coprime;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's `gcd()` recurses too deep and causes a *stack overflow*. [@OldProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909019/pi-calculator-program-gives-different-output-each-time-its-run/47909740#comment82785543_47909019)

Consider a replacement recursive function that is more efficient

Use FP math when doing the division

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned gcdu(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  return (b == 0) ? a : gcdu(b, a % b);
}

int main(void) {
  srand(time(0));

  int numberOne = rand();
  int numberTwo = rand();
  int coprime = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
    numberOne = rand();
    numberTwo = rand();
    if (gcdu(numberOne, numberTwo) == 1) {
      coprime++;
    }
  }

  // double pi = 599994 / coprime;
  double pi = 1.0*599994 / coprime;  //Insure FP division
  pi = sqrt(pi);
  printf("%f\n", pi);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
3.142940
```

Comment: FWIW, a high-ish recursion depth of  39 was noted with `gcdu(774542945, 2027634402)`.  With OP's original code, the depth could be 1000's millions `gcd(1000000000,1)`.

Comment: `gcdu(1276900689, 2066068658)` recursed 41 times.  Hmmm, wonder what is the limit?